# Android, Background service is not starting

Tags: java, android

I am implementing a simple application executing a background service, I am not able to start the     service, following is my Manifest & Code, the service class is properly resolved ( reading resources ), inheriting from IntentService ( and implementing the req methods ) doesn't resolve the problem as-well...

Why does the Background service doesn't start? 
any help will be appreciated.

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.newcomp.vagent"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver android:name="com.newcomp.Infrastructure.BootStarter" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name=".CaptureService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":captureService" >
    </service>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

</manifest>
```

Service code:

```
package com.newcomp.vagent;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.R.*;
import android.os.IBinder;

import java.io.IOException;

import fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD;

    public class CaptureService extends Service {
    public CaptureService() {
        //super("Capture Service");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

Activity code:
    package com.newcomp.vagent;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final String strSvcName = getResources().getString(R.string.startup_service);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), String.format("Hello from '%s'", strSvcName), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Class cls = null;
        try {
            cls = getClassLoader().loadClass(strSvcName);
            startService(new Intent(this, cls));// Starts the service
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No special error, startService doesn't throw any exception, Logcat is saying "348-763/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Start proc com.newcomp.vagent:captureService for service com.newcomp.vagent/.CaptureService: pid=1773 uid=10074 gids={50074, 9997, 3003, 1028, 1015}..." which indicate that the service IS started... though no breakpoint is met...

Comment: Oh ok. Well I am noticing a few things that might point you in the right direction (hopefully), your service isn't inheriting from IntentService but from the regular service class. And your service starting code is very complicated, why not just startService(new Intent(this, CaptureService.class));

Comment: May be, I think service is started properly, but you are not doing any operation in onStartCommand, try put atleast log in it, and check, please.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was simple, the service was actually starting but since **android:process=":captureService"** was specified it was starting on a separate process, one that is not connected by the debugger, either specifcally connecting to the service process, OR, omitting **android:process=":captureService"** resolve the problem.